# What's wrong with my code? - HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a simple table and hide all the other options column when user select an option. I'm afraid that the error in some HTML syntax.

HTML:

```js
       $('#data').change(function() {
         $('.hideShowTr').css('display','none');
         $('tr#' + $(this).val()).css('display','block');
      });
```

```html
    <select id="data">
        <option value="#">select</option>
        <option value="fiat">FIAT</option>
        <option value="gm">GM</option>
        <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>

        </select></td>
     <td colspan="5" class="escreve">
   
      <table width="650" border="1">
        <tr>
         <td> Requisito de Pintura </td>
         <td> Aplicação do Teste</td>
         <td> Quantidade Amostras por Teste</td>
         <td> Laboratório a ser realizados os testes</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="hideShowTr" id="fiat" style="display: none;">
         <td>Teste realizado em e-coat </td>
         <td>Roda</td>  
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideShowTr" id="gm" style="display: none;">
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
         <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
         <td>XXXXX</td>
        </tr>
       <tr class="hideShowTr" id="mitsubishi" style="display: none;">
        <td> xxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>xxxxxxxx<br>xxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>xxxxxxx</td>
       </tr></td>
    </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You haven't included the **jQuery** library? I suggest you open your browser console, this will display errors which will help when debugging. Also where is your `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: In what way does this not work?

Comment: It's embarrassing 'cause it's working on jsfiddle, but I tried to run .HTML and its not working.

Yes, I included my library and my .js

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="SIT.js"</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @NewToJS there are no errors when debugging.

Comment: @user2287892 Add the **jQuery Library** before your **SIT.JS** Order matters, if it hasn't read the library then the JS run before that will have errors.

Comment: @NewToJS I added jQuery before I got no errors, when I added .js before jQuery I got the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is malformed. Use this:

```
<select id="data">
  <option value="#">select</option>
  <option value="fiat">FIAT</option>
  <option value="gm">GM</option>
  <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
</select>

<table width="650" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> Requisito de Pintura </td>
    <td> Aplicação do Teste</td>
    <td> Quantidade Amostras por Teste</td>
    <td> Laboratório a ser realizados os testes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="fiat" style="display: none;">
    <td>Teste realizado em e-coat </td>
    <td>Roda</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="gm" style="display: none;">
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="mitsubishi" style="display: none;">
    <td> xxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

also for `tr` you should use `display: table-row` otherwise the cells won't line up:

```
$('#data').change(function() {
  $('.hideShowTr').css('display', 'none');
  $('tr#' + $(this).val()).css('display', 'table-row');
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/L1mtuc5m/1/**

Comment: +1 This answer removes your extra <td> tags.  Those extra <td> tags would have caused some serious issues.

Comment: @Miguel Mota JSFIDDLE working perfectly. When I try to run here on my PC it does not work. No errors when I try to debugging too.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error on that jQuery, fix it like this:

```
  $('#data').change(function() {
     $('.hideShowTr').css('display','none');
     $('#' + $(this).val()).css('display','block');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is malformed AND the JS block must be declared with a slight change for it to work. Display shouldn;t change to `block`. Just unsetting it (blank) should do.

```js
$('#data').change(function() {
     $('.hideShowTr').css('display', 'none');
     $('tr#' + $(this).val()).css('display', '');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="data">
  <option value="#">select</option>
  <option value="fiat">FIAT</option>
  <option value="gm">GM</option>
  <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
</select>

<table width="650" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Requisito de Pintura </th>
    <th> Aplicação do Teste</th>
    <th> Quantidade Amostras por Teste</th>
    <th> Laboratório a ser realizados os testes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="fiat" style="display: none;">
    <td>Teste realizado em e-coat </td>
    <td>Roda</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="gm" style="display: none;">
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>THIS ELEMENT WAS MISSING</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hideShowTr" id="mitsubishi" style="display: none;">
    <td> xxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxxxxx</td>
    <td>xxxxxxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```